# my BinarySearch code is not working.What is the issue with my code?

Tags: java, binary-search

I am trying to write the code of the Binary search in Java. But the cursor is just stack and cant see any answer. Please i need help to resolve the issue. I believe the code i have written makes sense though. Not sure!

```
public class BinarySearch {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int test[] = {1, 3, 5, 6};

    // int ans = BinarySearch(test, 6);

    System.out.println(BinarySearch(test, 1));
    //while (counter <=test.length){
    //System.out.println(test[counter]);
    //counter++;
}

public static int BinarySearch(int searcharr[], int key) {

    int left, fulllength, midpoint;

    left = 0;
    midpoint = 0;
    fulllength = searcharr.length;

    while (left <= fulllength) {

        midpoint = (left + fulllength) / 2;

        if (searcharr[midpoint] == key) {

            return searcharr[midpoint];

        } else if (searcharr[midpoint] > key) {
            left = midpoint - 1;
        } else {
            fulllength = midpoint + 1;
        }
        // left++;
    }
    return -1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a very small issue

```
// searcharr[midpoint] = 5
//  5 > 1   , execute else if , mean
//  1  3  5  6
//     ^  should be new fulllength = mid-1 

// what you are doing is 
//  1  3  5  6
//     ^  left = mid-1 which is wrong

else if (searcharr[midpoint] > key) {
            left = midpoint - 1;
        }     
else {
      fulllength = midpoint + 1;
    }
```

so final code would be

```
   while (left<=fulllength){

        midpoint = (left + fulllength)/2;
        System.out.println(midpoint + " "+left+" "+fulllength);

        if(searcharr[midpoint]==key)
        {
           //return searcharr[midpoint];
           return midpoint; // return position instead of value 
        }
        else if (searcharr[midpoint]>key)
        {
           fulllength = midpoint - 1;
        }
        else 
        {
          left = midpoint + 1;
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you soo much Rahul and Paveneet_Singh. It is working now! i will send you a quick message for explanation into details

Answer (score 0):

You started your high key at incorrect index and the logical comparison inside your if statement was incorrect. You also set changed your left and fulllength incorrectly at the end of every loop. They're supposed to be swapped. This should work.

```
public static int BinarySearch(int searcharr[], int key) {

int left, fulllength, midpoint;

left = 0;
midpoint = 0;
fulllength = searcharr.length - 1; //fulllength starts at incorrect index.

while (left <= fulllength) {

    midpoint = (left + fulllength) / 2;

    if (searcharr[midpoint] == key) {

        return searcharr[midpoint];
        // the comparison inside was incorrect
    } else if (searcharr[midpoint] < key) {
        left = midpoint + 1; //instead of midpoint - 1
    } else {
        fulllength = midpoint - 1; //instead of midpoint + 1
    }
    // left++;
}
return -1;
}
```